# How to Disable the add-in button when ArcMap is started?

Tags: arcmap, add-in

Question 1:How to Disable the add-in button when the ArcMap started,then I use the SelectByRectangletool  select features,then the button enabled! I am a fresh man about the add-in.

Question 2:I made a menu as show ,As the figure shows, how to avoid the part of in red rectangle,because the menu do not have the child menu again,but it is show the arrow ,and part of the child menu.

I means the tool’s skin is gray，and it is not activate

[image: question 1:tool gray， not activate]

[image: question 2 :My custom toolbar with the menu click here]

I am sorry about my poor engilsh

here is the question2's config.esriaddinx file:

```
<ArcMap>
  <Commands>
    <Button id="Yangtze_University_GRP_Mult" class="Mult" message="new" caption="test" tip="tip" category="Add-In Controls" image="Images\1.png" />
    <MultiItem id="ESRI_SelectionSample_MultiItem" caption="MultiItem AddIn" class="ZoomToLayerMultiItem" >
    </MultiItem>
  </Commands>
  <Menus>
    <!--main menu-->
    <Menu id="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu" caption="MainMenu" isRootMenu="true">
      <Items>
        <Menu refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_2" />
        <Menu refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_1" />
      </Items>
    </Menu>
    <!--submenu-->
    <Menu id="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_2" caption="New file" isRootMenu="false">
      <Items>
        <!--<Button refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_Mult" />-->
        <Menu refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_3" />
        <Menu refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_4" />
        <Menu refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_5" />
        <MultiItem refID="ESRI_SelectionSample_MultiItem" />
      </Items>
    </Menu>
    <!--third menu-->
    <Menu id="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_3" caption="test1" isRootMenu="false" isShortcutMenu="true" />
    <Menu id="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_4" caption="test2" isRootMenu="false" isShortcutMenu="true" />
    <Menu id="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu_5" caption="test3" isRootMenu="false" isShortcutMenu="true" />
  </Menus>
  <Toolbars>
    <Toolbar id="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Toolbar" caption="toolbar" showInitially="true">
      <Items>
        <Menu refID="Yangtze_University_GRP_My_Menu" />
      </Items>
    </Toolbar>
  </Toolbars>
</ArcMap>
```

Comment: Do you mean [enable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enable?s=ts), [unable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unable?s=t), [disable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disable?s=t), or something entirely different? It's difficult to determine. As it is, I don't know if you want to disable the button or are unable to do so.

Comment: You have two different questions here.  I would suggest for you to create a secondary question for number 2 so it may get it own attention.

Answer (score 2):

To have a button enabled pending a condition, you first have to change one of the parameters in the Config.esriaddinx file. This is in the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Advanced_add_in_concepts/0001000004n7000000/) under Delay loading section. You have to include 'onDemand="false"' in the button declaration, like this

```
<Button id="ESRI_SelectionSample_ToggleDockWinBtn" class="ToggleDockWinBtn" caption="Toggle Dockable Window" category="Framework AddIn Samples" image="Images\ToggleDockWinBtn.png" tip="Toggle dockable window." message="Toggle dockable window." onDemand="false">
```

Then in the code for your button, you'll have to add in the OnUpdate sub, which will enable or diable the button depending on the condition. It sounds like you'll want to check whether there are selected features in your feature class.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()

    Me.Enabled = pSelectionSet.Count > 0

End Sub
```

For your second question, can you post your Config.esriaddinx file?

*Edit

Here is the Config.esriaddinx I use to create this toolbar for an extension.

[image]

```
<ArcMap>
  <Commands>
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ImportScheme" class="ImportScheme" message="Import Classification Scheme from Table" caption="Import from Table" tip="Import Scheme from Table" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ImportScheme_1.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Compatibility" class="Compatibility" message="Check shapefile/classification scheme compatibility" caption="Check Compatibility" tip="Check the shapefile for fields needed in classification scheme" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\Compatibility.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_CreateLegend" class="CreateLegend" message="Add Legend to existing shapefile from classification scheme." caption="Add Legend" tip="Add Legend to existing shapefile from classification scheme." category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\CreateLegend.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_AttributeSelection" class="AttributeSelection" message="Attribute Selection" caption="Attribute Selection" tip="Attribute Selection" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\AttributeSelection.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ExportScheme" class="ExportScheme" message="Export Classification Scheme to Table" caption="Export Scheme" tip="Export Scheme to Table" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ExportScheme.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ExportSchemeAsText" class="ExportSchemeAsText" message="Save Classification Scheme to Text File" caption="Save to Text" tip="Save Scheme to Text File" category="Add-In Controls" image="Images\ExportSchemeAsText.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_FieldInfo" class="FieldInfo" message="View Field Requirements for Classification Scheme" caption="View Field Information" tip="View Field Requirements for Classification Scheme" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\FieldInfo.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Integration" class="Integration" message="Automatically integrate layer when exiting Edit mode" caption="Automatically Integrate" tip="Automatically integrate layer when exiting Edit mode" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\Integration.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ModifyScheme" class="ModifyScheme" message="Modify existing classification scheme" caption="Modify Existing Scheme" tip="Modify existing classification scheme" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ModifyScheme.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_NewFeatureClass" class="NewFeatureClass" message="Create new feature class" caption="New Feature Class" tip="Create new feature class" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\NewFeatureClass.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_NewScheme" class="NewScheme" message="Create new classification scheme" caption="New scheme" tip="Create new classification scheme" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\NewScheme.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_RepairMismatch" class="RepairMismatch" message="Repairs mismatch between ID and attributes in shapefile" caption="Repair Attributes" tip="Repairs mismatch between ID and attributes in shapefile" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\RepairMismatch.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Settings" class="Settings" message="Set Scale and MMU Settings" caption="Settings" tip="Set Scale and MMU Settings" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\Settings.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ShowDictionary" class="ShowDictionary" message="View Classification Scheme Information" caption="View Scheme Information" tip="View Classification Scheme Information" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ShowDictionary.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ViewClassificationScheme" class="ViewClassificationScheme" message="View Classification Scheme Hierarchy" caption="View Scheme Hierarchy" tip="View Classification Scheme Hierarchy" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ViewClassificationScheme.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Tool id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_MMUGraphic" class="MMUGraphic" message="Add MMU Box" caption="Add MMU Box" tip="Add MMU box to display" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\MMUGraphic_1.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ValidateSDE" class="ValidateSDE" message="Validate scheme for SDE workspaces" caption="Validate scheme for SDE" tip="Validate scheme for SDE workspaces" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ValidateSDE_1.png" onDemand="false" />
    <Button id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ViewValidation" class="ViewValidation" message="Show Validated Workspaces" caption="Show Validated Workspaces" tip="Show Validated Workspaces" category="Habitat Digitizer" image="Images\ViewValidation_1.png" onDemand="false" />
  </Commands>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Extension" class="Extension" productName="Habitat Digitizer" showInExtensionDialog="true" autoLoad="true">
      <Description>Habitat Digitizer Extension 6.0&#xD;&#xA;NOAA/NOS/NCCOS/CCMA/Biogeography Branch&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Provides the ability to use hierarchical classification schemes to &#xD;&#xA;rapidly delineate and attribute polygons, lines, and points.</Description>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
  <Toolbars>
    <Toolbar id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Habitat_Digitizer_Toolbar_1" caption="Habitat Digitizer" showInitially="false">
      <Items>
        <Menu refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Habitat_Digitizer" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_NewFeatureClass" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_MMUGraphic" />
      </Items>
    </Toolbar>
  </Toolbars>
  <Menus>
    <Menu id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Habitat_Digitizer" caption="Habitat Digitizer" isRootMenu="true">
      <Items>
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_NewScheme" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ModifyScheme" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ImportScheme" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ValidateSDE" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ExportScheme" separator="true" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ExportSchemeAsText" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ViewClassificationScheme" separator="true" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ViewValidation" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_ShowDictionary" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_FieldInfo" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Compatibility" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_RepairMismatch" separator="true" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_CreateLegend" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Settings" separator="true" />
        <Button refID="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_Integration" separator="true" />
      </Items>
    </Menu>
  </Menus>
  <Editor>
    <Extensions>
      <Extension id="Biogeography_Branch_HabitatDigitizer_10_EditorExtension" class="EditorExtension" />
    </Extensions>
  </Editor>
</ArcMap>
```

Comment: I have post the config file in the arcticle ,thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To set your button enable state to false you have to set the `onDemand = "False"` within the Config.esriaddinx file.

To further change the button enable/disable state you set this within the OnUpdate() sub within the button class usually based on some sort of conditional check.  The example below looks for selected layer in TOC or not.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()

        Try
            Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument = Nothing

            Dim app As IApplication

            app = CType(Hook, IApplication)
            pMxDoc = CType(app.Document, IMxDocument)

            Dim pMap As IMap
            pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap

            Dim pSelItem As Object
            pSelItem = pMxDoc.SelectedItem
            ' Disable if the selected item is nothing or if
            ' it is not a layer or table
            If pSelItem Is Nothing Then
                Enabled = My.ArcMap.Application IsNot Nothing = False
            ElseIf Not (TypeOf pSelItem Is ILayer Or TypeOf pSelItem Is IStandaloneTable) Then
                Enabled = My.ArcMap.Application IsNot Nothing = False
            Else
                Enabled = My.ArcMap.Application IsNot Nothing = True
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```